# How to use crossplatform/standard sed between linux and mac?

Tags: awk, sed

Hi I have one script that was running inside makefiles for project deployments.
I use sed inside it to capture environment and project name from input string and in ubuntu works great.

This simple command

```
 echo deploy-api-production | sed -E 's/deploy-\w+-(\w+)/\1/'
```

gives expected result `production` in ubuntu

ubuntu execution

```
$  echo deploy-api-production | sed -E 's/deploy-\w+-(\w+)/\1/'
production
```

but in mac gives the entire full string `deploy-api-production`

mac execution:

```
$  echo deploy-api-production | sed -E 's/deploy-\w+-(\w+)/\1/'
deploy-api-production
```

Is there some kind of unified sed so I get same result in mac as well?

I want output to be only production in mac execution as well

**Case 2 - more generic, including prefix as well**

Want to parse this properly

```
echo a-deploy-api-production | someprocessing
production
```

So is similar to above case, but does has one extra prefix word `a-` before the word `deploy`

I tried something similar to current given solution but did not work

```
echo a-deploy-api-production | awk -F'-' '$1=="a-deploy"{print $3}'
```

result of above is empty, want to modify to get result `production`

Comment: Neither `\w` nor `+` are POSIX `sed`.

Comment: Hi the command I provided works fine on ubuntu. Can you please tell me what to use instead to get it work cross platform ?

Comment: The portable form of `\w` is `[[:alnum:]]`; the portable form of `+` is `{1,}` (one or more occurences). So your litetal command is `sed -E 's/deploy-[[:alnum:]]{1,}-([[:alnum:]]{1,})/\1/'`. But in the end, it seems you are looking for `sed '/deploy-/s/.*-//'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
echo deploy-api-production | awk -F'-' '$1=="deploy"{print $3}'
```

This splits the text into parts separated by `-`. It requires the first field to match the word `deploy` and then prints the third.

In your updated question you include a new variation. You cannot use the same `awk` code to directly compare `a-deploy` because that's two fields (remember, they are split by the dash), and `$1` is only the first field (i.e. `a` instead of `deploy` in this new instance).

Without knowing all your use-cases I would suggest you may be happier to search for `deploy` anywhere in the string, and if it's found then print the last field. (This will also work for your original case.)

```
echo deploy-api-production | awk -F'-' '/deploy/ {print $NF}'
production

echo a-deploy-api-production | awk -F'-' '/deploy/ {print $NF}'
production
```

Comment: I tested on mac and ubuntu and works totally fine. Thank you for the knowledge here, marked as answer. For my learning, what if i add onoe extra word before deploy, this won't work for example `echo a-deploy-api-production | awk -F'-' '$1=="a-deploy"{print $3}'` I tried specifying also print $4 as I added one extra word `a-` before deploy still did not work

Comment: Thanks updated question and added case 2

Comment: @KristiJorgji there you go

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX-*ly* `sed`, you can attain the required results for both scenarios, as shown:

```bsh
w='[[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*'
echo 'deploy-api-productionN' | 
sed -n -e "/^\($w-\)\{0,1\}deploy-/s/^$w\(-\($w\)\)\{1,\}\$/\2/p"
```

---

Observations:

- since sed has no symbol for a word, we will build a regex for that and store them in shell variable **$w**
- \{0,1\} is BRE for ?
- \{1,\} is BRE for +
- \(...\) is BRE for (...)

Answer (score 0):

You get different results on the two systems because the GNU system uses a regular expression library that was extended to include some symbols from the type of regular expressions called `PCRE` (*Perl Compatible Regular Expressions*).  These symbols, like `\s` and `\w`, are not standard and not supported with `sed` on all systems (typically not outside of GNU systems).

You seem to want to output the last part of a line after the last `-` (dash) if it starts with the substring `deploy` or `something-deploy`.

You can do that with standard `sed` using

```bsh
sed '/^deploy/ s/.*-//'
```

or with

```bsh
sed '/^something-deploy/ s/.*-//'
```

These `sed` expressions trigger the substitution `s/.*-//` if the preceding regular expression matches the current input line.  Thi substitution removes everything up to and including the last dash on the line.

You can combine the triggering expression with the substitution in this case, if you want:

```bsh
sed 's/^deploy.*-//'
```

```bsh
sed 's/^something-deploy.*-//'
```

If your data is not static strings outputted by `echo` (as in the question) but some value in a variable, then it would be more efficient to let the shell do this rather than calling an external program:

```bsh
string=deploy-api-production

if [[ $string == deploy-* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${string##*-}"
fi
```

You will use a variable assignment rather than `printf` if you want to hold on to the modified value, as in `new=${string##*-}`.

The `${variable##pattern}` expansion will remove the longest prefix string from `$variable` that matches the shell pattern `pattern`.